# How to handle consequence of zero's in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Let's take an ex:

Suppose if the user entered in text filed value like 00000 e.t.c 
I want to treat it like as 0 only.
Filed accept's only numbers

Comment: please add some more information about any other values to enter in this field. do you have only numbers or other characters as well?

Comment: Try use REGEXP as an input validation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: only numbers @NinaScholz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to parse a string to number is Number constructor (not only integer)

```
Number("0000.14"); // 0.14
Number("000000") // 0
```

or you can add plus sign before a strings

```
+"00000" // 0
+"000.12" // 0.12
```

Comment: Thanq so much Narek.  it's working Number("000000")

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the value from a text field, it will be treated as a string. Assuming integer values, all you need to do is use the `parseInt` function with the string input as the first argument and the radix (10, assuming the entered value is in decimal) as the second argument:

```
parseInt('0010', 10);
// 10
```